# what is the main difference between the Main and custom route table with suitable real time example?

Tags: amazon-web-services, routetable

I understood how to create and edit the custom and main route tables. I found some AWS questions with both options(Main vs Custom). We have to select the best one. How they differ and when I have to use a custom route table over Main route table with suitable example? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A **Main** route table will be automatically used by **any subnet that has not been specifically assigned to a Route Table**.

So, just think of it as the "Default" route table.

It is also possible to specifically assign a subnet to the Main route table.

Some people think that every subnet should be explicitly assigned a route table to avoid any potential configuration problems, but the choice is yours.

Comment: just to add more: in the 4 scenarios AWS doc describes(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario3.html), public subnets are always associated with custom route table while private subnets are always associated with main table, I think the reason is the main(default) table doesn't come with internet gateway: "the main route table contains only a local route. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Route_Tables.html"